# azure update tuple data Asp.net MVC with c# sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

i have asp.net base c# and sql database application,
I have action method for my orders and inside of this action method i'm calculating total price for my Order and it works just fine in my local machine (calculate and save to db),
but in my azure server it doesn't calculate total (db Order Total=null),this is action method :

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
  if (id == null)
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  //get order
  Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
  //retrieve all the OrderItems belong to Order
  var orderItems =order.OrderItems;
  //caculate total 
  decimal total = 0;
  foreach (var i in orderItems)
  {
    decimal price = i.Quantity * i.UnitPrice;
    total += price;
  }
  //set OrderTotal to Total 
  order.OrderTotal = total;
  db.SaveChanges();
  if (order == null)
  {
    return HttpNotFound();
  }
  return View(order);
}
```

Comment: Are you pointing to a different database when you publish to your Azure server?  Maybe there are no orders / order items created in that db.

Comment: i'm pushing to right database,also Order and OrderItems created and added to database ,i checked my db table data and all exist.

Comment: just FIY,i'm creating my Order first and pushing OrderITems by calling my method with Ajax ,it works fine.then I finalize Order and calculate total and set it for my Order .

Comment: Also tried it with different query for OrderItems var orderItems =from j in db.OrderItems where j.OrderId == id select j; both queries working fine in local machine. and In my Details Order view i'm catching my orders with OrderItems but total for my Order is null .